# Can't change keyboard layout selection

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I was given an ubuntu 10.10 machine with the following weird thing: it has several 'US' keyboard layouts in list (and hotkey cycling). When I open System - Preferences - Keyboard and try to fix, I can delete extra layouts, but:

1. GTK skin on all windows changes to something default and ugly.
2. After relogin, everything is back.

I have tried applying changes system-wide and from root, changing keyboard Input Method. I have checked file access rights on my home folder are OK. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the GTK theme is changing, the most likely cause is that `gnome-settings-manager` is crashing. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gnome-settings-manager`. You should get your settings back. If not, try running `gnome-settings-manager` from a terminal so you can see any error messages.

Note that this answer might not help with your original keyboard problem. But it might. And if you can confirm that `gnome-settings-manager` is the culprit, then you'll have a [bug you can report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/) and you'll have some more info to go on.